# Is there a better way to allow my WPF app to connect to AWS RDS than individually whitelisting IPs in security group?

Tags: c#, wpf, passwords, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I have a WPF app that connects to AWS RDS SQL Server Express database and every time I am connecting from a new IP I have log in to AWS and add an inbound rule to allow MS SQL to connect to my new IP. I just keep whitelisting new IPs.

It seems cumbersome and perhaps not secure, and allowing "connect from anywhere" seems even less secure. Is there a way so my app could always connect, securely, without perpetually adding new IPs to the security groups?

I've done a lot of Googling and security seems like a dense topic - sorry if this has been asked, I tried searching for it here but don't know exactly what I'm looking for.

To give context, my app allows various CRM APIs to interact with each other and the SQL Server database stores settings and credentials, so it's imperative that it be secure

Comment: Why your IP keeps changing? Are you switching between networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate the process of adding a Security Group rule, such as:

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "Foo-SG" --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr $IP/32 --profile class --output text
```

Just be careful because there is a limit on the number of rules in a Security Group.